# Do an ajax call to server.js from a vue app, using heroku

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku

I have followed this tutorial with success :

https://medium.com/p/a69845ace489/responses/show

Now, how can I do an ajax call **from my dist directory using vue axios**, to my server.js node file ?

Because heroku is giving randoms ports to my connexion with process.env.PORT.

This is my server config in main.js, inside the vue.js app, inside the dist directory :

```
Vue.server = Vue.prototype.server = "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/";
```

Please notice that there is no port, cause i can't know which port is used by heroku.

This is an axios random call, from the vue.js app

```
axios.post(Vue.server + "getUser", {id: this.id})
    .then(response => {
        this.user = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (erreur) {
        console.log(erreur);
    });
```

This is my server.js file :

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);console.log('server started '+ port);
```

My problem is that the port cant be set in my vue app, all of the rest of the code is working, i dont include the node rest stuff.

Do you think that keeping localhost as a Vue.server variable would work online ?
Thank you

**PART 2 :**

Changed my server.js file like this , added a getUsers post web service :

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;

const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

app.post("/getUsers", function(req, res) {
   res.send('ok');
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started '+ port);
```

2. This is my Helloworld.vue now :

   ```
   import axios from "axios";
   axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
   export default {
     name: 'HelloWorld',
     props: {
       msg: String
     },methods: {
       getUsers: function () {

               axios
                   .post("http://localhost/" + "getUsers", {
                   })
                   .then(response => {
                      console.log(response);
                   })
                   .catch(function (error) {
                       console.log(error);
                   });
           }
           },
       created: function () {
           this.getUsers();

       }
   }
   </script>
   ```

2.5 : on my localhost server, all is working well, the ajax call is working with no CORS error at all :

```
node server.js
```

3. Uploading this to HEROKU :

> git push heroku master

4. This is the error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
>   reading the remote resource at http://localhost/getUsers. (Reason:
>   CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: Why do you need to know the port? If your server is up, and you can get to it in the browser, then you're done. By definition as far as your clients (e.g. browser) are concerned, your server is running on port 80, even if the _internal_ port is not port 80. The error you're showing has nothing to do with ports, and everything to do with the fact that you're trying to POST to `localhost`, instead of your actual domain that you've set up on heroku. Start by just posting to `/getUsers`, not `http://localhost/getUsers`

Comment: Thanks it is working now ! Changed .post("http://localhost") ... to .post("https://vuestarter2.herokuapp.com/") ... and there is no error any more, I'm correctly receiving the "ok" message, thank a lot Mike ! The problem is when I'm working on localhost, I still have to switch the server name inside of my VUE app, do I have to set it inside of my  package .json .scripts file? HO sorry I see that you say to type getUsers Only Im trying out this.

Comment: Started by just posting to /getUsers, not http://localhost/getUsers and it works perfectly online AND on localhost without changing anything else, it is perfect thanks a lot Mike, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Let me turn it into an answer for you, although it might make more sense to delete again as it's closer to a typo than anything else =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently has the POST location hardcoded to `localhost`, which is guaranteed to not work on heroku (or any other hosting service for that matter).

Instead, don't even hardcode "the correct domain", just POST directly to `/getUsers`, without any explicit domain, and the browser will do the right thing regardless of the domain you're on (named, plain IP, WLAN, LAN, it'll just work).